# MvvmCross - How to make navigation call to Mvx View from UIApplication Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

My goal is to redirect user back to login screen after idle timed out. I have this code to countdown after each click/touch. It works well but my current problem is I have no idea to redirect user back to login screen. Since this is MvvmCross 4.4 project, there is not much documentation to look for. If I can also get the example code for Android, that would be very helpful. I will appreciate.

Below is the code I put in Main.cs

```
public class Application{  

    static void Main(string[] args){  
        //UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");  
        UIApplication.Main(args, "MyApplication", "AppDelegate");  
    }  

}  

//DELEGATE  
[Register("MyApplication")]  
public class MyApplication : UIApplication {  

    public override void SendEvent(UIEvent uievent) {  
        base.SendEvent(uievent);  
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;  
        if (allTouches.Count > 0) {  
            var phase = ((UITouch)allTouches.AnyObject).Phase;  
            if (phase == UITouchPhase.Began || phase == UITouchPhase.Ended)  
                ResetIdleTimer();  
        }  
    }  

    NSTimer idleTimer;  
    void ResetIdleTimer() {  
        if (idleTimer != null) {  
            idleTimer.Invalidate();  
            idleTimer.Dispose();  
        }  

        idleTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5), TimerExceeded);  
    }  

    void TimerExceeded(NSTimer obj) {  

        MvxiOSToastService toastService = new MvxiOSToastService();
        toastService.DisplayMessageAndDoSomething("You are going to be timed out.","Idle time exceeded.", RedirectToLogin);  

        Console.WriteLine("idle time exceeded");  
    }  

    void RedirectToLogin() {  

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;  
        var vc = window.RootViewController;  

        //ERROR HERE  
        var nextVC = new LoginView();   
        vc.ShowViewController(nextVC, this);  
        //----------
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to resolve the instance of your view presenter and get the currently presented view from there. Once you have that, you can access the ViewModel object and make the below calls to use MvvmCross navigation.

If you have access to the `RootViewController` then

```cs
void RedirectToLogin() {  
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;  
    var vc = window.RootViewController;  

    var mvxView = vc as IMvxIosView;  
    var vm = mvxView.ViewModel;

    vm.ShowViewModel<TViewModel>();
}
```

### MvvmCross before 5

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters

```cs
ShowViewModel<TViewModel>()
```

### MvvmCross 5+

Resolve an instance of your navigation service and use that to make the navigation call to your login screen.

So something like:

```cs
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>().Navigate<LoginViewModel>();
```

Comment: Excuse me. Is it possible in MvvmCross 4.4? If not, what else can be done?

Comment: Oh shoot, I realize this was introduced in MvvmCross 5. Let me find the 4.4 method of doing the same thing.

Comment: As I understood, ShowViewModel is the method in MvvmCross.Core.ViewModel, used many times in shared project, but I have to navigate to Login screen from UIApplication which is in iOS project. How could I do that? Thank you.

Comment: @rockman_t In your UIApplciaiton you can resolve what the currently presented ViewModel is by resolving the view presented and using a `IMvxIosView` conversion from a `UIViewController` to then resolve the ViewModel instance. From there you can call the `ShowViewModel()` from the ViewModel object.

Comment: Would you mind to demonstrate how to do it?
        
    void RedirectToLogin() {
            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var vc = window.RootViewController;
            
           //WHAT IS IT HERE?
    }

Comment: Yeah, you're really close to what you need. I'll update my answer with how to get the ViewModel from the RootViewController. I'm working on my knowledge of MvvmCross 5 instead of 4, so let me know if what I'm saying is not possible for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not possible. mvxView is null and if it's not null, vm does not contain ShowViewModel()

Comment: Okay, I've been basing this answer off my knowledge of 5.7, I'll spin up a 4.4 project later today and find something that works. I'll update this answer again once I have something working.

Comment: OMG. It turns out to be very easy. Just create an instance of MvxViewModel and call ShowModel<ViewModel>(); 

lol
Garrett, Thanks a lot